# multi language in Component

Tags: java, swing, fonts, multilingual

I am using Swing, and I need the components to be able to display multiple languages at the same time (inside one component). However, the characters other than English characters are displayed as squares.

The Components are just `JTextPane`, `JEditorPane`, `JTextField`, `JTextArea` and all the default stuff.

What must I do to achieve the goal of multi language support?

Comment: Most likely the font or your Operating System you're using does not support the characters you want to display, this is most likely not a Java issue.

Comment: Try to play with setFont() using the fonts which support the chars for the components

Comment: It probably has more to do with the fonts used.  Try iterating the available fonts and check that [`Font.canDisplayUpTo(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplayUpTo-java.lang.String-) (where the `String` is the content of that text component) returns -1.  As an experiment, set that `Font` for each component.

Comment: What I meant was:  *..(where the String is the content of that **part of the** text component) .. As an experiment, set that `Font` for each **language**.*

Answer (score 1):

On most platforms, the default *logical* [font family](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) specified by each component's UI delegate has the required glyphs for supported locales. If you override these defaults with a particular *physical* font using `setFont()`, you may be able to get the desired result using `deriveFont()`, as suggested in theses [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A230513%20derivefont). If you must use a particular *physical* font, you'll have to verify that the required glyphs are present. [`FontShower`](http://mindprod.com/applet/fontshower.html) may be a useful adjunct.

Answer (score 1):

Use a full [Unicode font](http://www.unifont.org/fontguide/). They are large. Then `setFont(...)` does the trick.

If you want to pack a font with your application `loadFont` and `registerFont` will do.

```
    Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,
        getClass().getResourceAsStream("/..."));
    GraphicsEnvironment ge =
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    ge.registerFont(font);
```