# Java Application unsupported multiple languages

Tags: java

I wrote a simple java application with a TextArea. When I copy Chinese sentence from google translate and paste in my TextArea, many characters are unsupported and displayed as white boxes. But it doesn't happen on Console or System Text Editor softwares. Do those use different fonts for all the languages in the word? I am testing on Linux, Mac and Windows. Any help will be appreciated.
This my simple TextArea without any custom font,

```
JTextArea inputStr = new JTextArea();
```

Comment: I think this will help you out:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733375/multi-language-in-component